# BQ - Merge command inserts more than one row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-merge

Ran the following query which I expected to insert or update only one row. But the query inserted 24923 rows which is the total number of rows existing in the table at the time of running this command.

```
MERGE INTO `merch_meter.jira_issues` AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM `merch_meter.jira_issues`) AS SOURCE 
ON (SOURCE.issueid = TARGET.issueid AND TARGET.issueid='AL-2559' and TARGET.teamid='5') WHEN 
MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET issuetype = 'Release',issuepoints =0 ,teamid='5',jiraboardid='460', sprintId ='0',status='NEW',
                    sprintstartdate=null,sprintenddate=null,createddate=null,completeddate=null,lastupdateddate=null,lastupdateduser='XCELERATE',creatoremailaddress='test@homedepot.com',creatordisplayname='xcelerate',
                    creatoraccountid='xcelerate',creatorisactive=true,components='Release',labels='Release',issueName='RELEASE'
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (issueid, issuetype,issuepoints,teamid,jiraboardid, sprintId,status,
                    sprintstartdate,sprintenddate,createddate,completeddate,lastupdateddate,lastupdateduser,creatoremailaddress,creatordisplayname,
                    creatoraccountid,creatorisactive,components,labels,issueName ) VALUES ('AL-2559','Release',0,'5','460',null,'NEW',null,null,null,null,current_timestamp,'Xcelerate','test@homedepot.com','xcelerate','xcelerate',true,'Release',"Release",'RELEASE STORY');
```

Not sure why it is inserting more than a row. Does anyone have an answer for this behavior?

Comment: Hi - why do you think it will only insert 1 row? Your MERGE statement will take every record from merch_meter.jira_issues and and insert it into the target if it doesn’t match

Comment: Ahh, that's not what I want. I want a simple to update to run for given issue id if exists, else I want to insert it one record. Can I do it using merge command without multiple inserts?

Comment: In which case you need to add a WHERE clause with the issue id to your SELECT statement

Comment: Added the where condition like below and not it is not inserting any now. Not sure I added where condition in the right place. 


MERGE INTO `merch_meter.jira_issues` AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM `merch_meter.jira_issues` where issueid = 'AL-2559') AS SOURCE..

Comment: So if you just run the SELECT statement does it return any records? i.e. run this: SELECT * FROM merch_meter.jira_issues where issueid = 'AL-2559'